# Cannot write to/ cannot create directory (Read-only file system)

Tags: kali-linux, read-write

I have a dual boot system with Kali Linux and Windows. I have 4 four partitions, one with a Windows install, another with the Kali Linux installation and the other two left aside for storage of other personal media and files. Untill recently, I could do anything on any of the partitions. I now get the error:

```
Cannot write to ‘httpd-2.2.32.tar.gz’ (Read-only file system).
```

when I try do download anything to any of the two storage media, or

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Read-only file system
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

***/etc/fstab***

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=d2f577b6-54ca-4107-8cfb-df16b0ff041d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=8e0617c4-4693-4364-be85-b0cee15a5d4f none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

***/var/log/messages*** is completely blank. Nothing is logged in the file.

The last thing I remember doing that could have messed things up was logging into my linux with the Windows 10 on Hibernate mode. I don't know if this could have messed things up for me.

**lsblk**

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 150.4G  0 part /media/rev/63CA6D5A72F6F4CF
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 100.6G  0 part /media/rev/08BDB5EF06C52B43
├─sda4   8:4    0 100.6G  0 part /media/rev/5431214957EBF5D7
├─sda5   8:5    0   5.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 108.3G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: What is the contents of `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: And `/var/log/messages` - the system may have been able to log an event that precipitated the filesystem being mounted read-only.  If it was recent, you can also check the output of the `dmesg` ring buffer.

Comment: I just did an update @GAD3R with my **/etc/fstab**

Comment: Run `dmesg` to see the kernel log.  Apparently your system is not configured to write it to /var/log/mesages, so I'm guessing it is pure systemd, in which case you can use `journalctl` to read the systemd log.  The filesystem is probably damaged so you need to unmount and fsck it.